# Merge object where key is matching

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, array-merge

I'm new to typescript or node.js, I'm trying to combine the below JSON array
Note: Not sure if the client allows any new dependencies or plugins
can this be achieved without using underscore or jquery extend

```
[ { parentauthscopekey: 1, childauthscopekey: 2 },
  { parentauthscopekey: 12, childauthscopekey: 10 },
  { parentauthscopekey: 12, childauthscopekey: 11 },
  { parentauthscopekey: 13, childauthscopekey: 1 } ]
```

To

```
[ { parentauthscopekey: 1, childauthscopekey: [ 2, 1 ] },
  { parentauthscopekey: 12, childauthscopekey: [ 10, 11, 12 ] },
  { parentauthscopekey: 13, childauthscopekey: [ 1, 13 ] } ]
```

Tried the below code, It's just too many lines but does the job, but expecting something simple without using the hardcoded scope and scopeMap values

```
 table = [ { parentauthscopekey: 1, childauthscopekey: 2 },
  { parentauthscopekey: 12, childauthscopekey: 10 },
  { parentauthscopekey: 12, childauthscopekey: 11 },
  { parentauthscopekey: 13, childauthscopekey: 1 } ]
   
    scope=[1,12,13]
    scopeMap = new Set()

    table2 = []
    scope.forEach(parentauthscopekey => {
        table.forEach(row =>{
            if(row.parentauthscopekey == parentauthscopekey && !scopeMap.has(parentauthscopekey))
            {
                scopeMap.add(parentauthscopekey)
                childauthscopekey = []
                table.filter(c => c.parentauthscopekey == row.parentauthscopekey).forEach(r=>{
                    childauthscopekey.push(r.childauthscopekey)
                })
                childauthscopekey.push(parentauthscopekey)
                table2.push({parentauthscopekey, childauthscopekey})
            }
        })
    })
    console.log(table2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can  :

- use `array.reduce` to construct the expecting structure
- recover or each entry the child matching parentauthscopekey with `array.filter`
- and adding the current parentauthscopekey to childauthscopekey

```js
var data = [ { parentauthscopekey: 1, childauthscopekey: 2 },
  { parentauthscopekey: 12, childauthscopekey: 10 },
  { parentauthscopekey: 12, childauthscopekey: 11 },
  { parentauthscopekey: 13, childauthscopekey: 1 } ];
  
var result = data.reduce((acc, current) => {
    if (!acc.some(one => one.parentauthscopekey === current.parentauthscopekey)) {
      var childs = data.filter(one => one.parentauthscopekey === current.parentauthscopekey).map(one => one.childauthscopekey);
      childs.push(current.parentauthscopekey);
      acc.push({
        parentauthscopekey: current.parentauthscopekey,
        childauthscopekey: childs
      })
    }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: flawless. Thank you so much for your time and the code